# REST ASSURED: how to parse json response which contains "."

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

New to rest assured. I have a rest API JSON response like below, and I'd like to extract value of "value", how can I do it?

```
{
    "google.com": {
        "company": google,
        "state": "CA",
        "value": 123456789
    }
}
```

I have tried with below code:

```
extract().
    body().jsonPath().get("google.com")
```

got below exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get property 'com' on null object
```

then i realized "." is used to separate json path, also tried get("/google.com")

```
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line 1
```

Comment: made it work by    
`body("'google.com'.'value'", equalTo(123456789))`

Comment: Please check the JSON is incorrect. `"company": google,` should be `"company": "google",`